# robot framework - how to set variable to valueX if buffer contain a string else set to ValueY

Tags: python, robotframework

In robot framework how can you implement below python construct ?

```
  value = "value X" if 'string' in buffer else "value Y"
```

I tried using run keyword if, but the builtin 'Should contain' failed for SyntaxError. I have below line in RF

```
  run keyword if   should contain   ${buffer}   string   ignore_case=True   kw_to_set_variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [Set Variable If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If). For example:

```
${value}=  set variable if  'string' in $buffer  value x  value y
```

Answer (score -1):

If the values are returned from keywords, then the syntax you started with is the correct one - just need to add an ELSE construct:

```
${val}=    Run Keyword If    boolean_condition    keyword_if_true    ELSE    keyword_if_false
```

If `boolean_conditon` evaluates to true, `${val}` will be set to the return value of the keyword `keyword_if_true`, or to `keyword_if_false`'s otherwise.

This approach is an alternative to the accepted answer - Set Variable will reassign the value directly with something else, while this one will take return values of ran keywords.